# MAD outlier analysis in for loop

Tags: matlab, median, outliers

I'm running median absolute deviation outlier analysis on a matrix `B` (126 x 7). I thought my code below was working but I get an error about dimension mismatch. Can anyone help me? I'm still a beginner with MATLAB.

```
b = B; %identifying raw data for outlier analysis
k=size(B,2); %preallocating size of loop to run to be equivalent to number columns in B


for j= 1:k
    a=b(:,j); %identify data used
    fa = abs(a-median(a))./(mad(a,1)./.6745); %if x>3.5 then outlier
    dec_mad=fa>2.24; %logical operator identifying outlier
    nout(j)=sum(dec_mad); %sum of outliers
    x = dec_mad ==0; % logical of data with outliers removed
    b(:,j) = a(x); %data without outliers
end
```

Comment: Just a comment. The line `k=size(B,2);` is not pre-allocating anything, it is actually saving the value in a variable. You could pre-allocate the variable `a` with the expression `a=zeros(size(b))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the issue:

`b(:,j) = a(x);`

If `x` contains some zeros (i.e. outliers were found), the output of `a(x)` is smaller than your original `a`.  Therefore you are trying to replace `b(:,j)` - 126 values - with `a(x)` - less than 126 values, hence dimension mismatch.

You could just replace any outliers with `NaN`:

`b(dec_mad,j)=NaN;`

Or use a cell array which would allow your individual output columns to be different sizes.

`out{j} = a(x);`

Incidentally, it's best not to use `j` for loops, it's a MATLAB built-in for complex numbers.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much of your help! And thanks for the j hint, I thought the opposite - I thought you were meant to use it in loops.